# (ASP.NET 6 + React) IHostedService is blocking React from loading data from the backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-core

I have and modular application which runs on an ASP.NET 6 Web API + React, made by the following template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022

Now, in my ASP.NET application I have an IHostedService that is running two tasks continuously, which looks like follows (code abbreviated for clarity)

**IHostedService.cs**

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var task1 = Task1();
    var task2 = Task2(cancellationToken);
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}

private async Task Task1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{    
    while (true)
    {
       //runs code continuously
    }
}
   
private async Task Task2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{    
    while (true)
    {
       //runs code continuously
    }
}
```

Since in ASP.NET 6 there's no more `Startup.cs` I added my HostedService to `Program.cs` like following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.    
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My backend including  Task1 and Task2 from the IHostedService are running fine, however when my browser opens the ReactApp front-end it is stuck on loading since it's blocked by the IHostedService running continuous Tasks.

Now my question is, how can I prevent my IHostedService from blocking my React App from loading. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The host application starts each `IHostedService` in order, blocking until they have each started. You probably want `BackgroundService`, probably 2 of them. Note that the host will still block until the first `await` in your background service.

Comment: "Since in ASP.NET 6 there's no more Startup.cs" those templates still work. There's just an alternative now, which all the documentation uses instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line to the beginning of ExecuteAsync (the override from BackgroundService) fixes it.

```
await Task.Yield();
```